# Global names between main and shared library not visible

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I compiled a shared library with gcc and linked it to my main. The main class should initialize a logger class, which should be visible inside the shared library, but it looks as if the shared library has it's own instance of it.

The include file looks like this:

```
extern Log gLog;
```

In main it is declared.

```
Log gLog(new StreamWriter());
```

When I try to link it, I get linker errors `undefined symbol _gLog` in the shared library. I thought that it might be because it is a class instance, so I changed it to a pointer, but I get the same. To make it worse, I figured I could create a small dummy module where I create the same global variable in the shared library and then call a function to initialize it. But for this function I also get a linker error because it is not visible in main.

In the shared library:

```
Log *gLogger;

int initLibrary(Log *pLogger)
{
    gLogger = pLogger;
}
```

And in main:

```
Log gLog(new StreamWriter());
int initLibrary(Log *pLogger);
main()
{
    initLibrary(&gLog);
}
```

Again I get an undefined symbol in the linker, this time for my initLibrary function.

For now I solve the problem by creating a dummy class, which works. However, I would like to know how to properly define symbols across shared library boundaries, as my understanding seems to be wrong about it.

When using google I found some threads here [Using a global variable in a shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291796/using-a-global-variable-in-a-shared-library) and [Global variables, shared libraries and -fPIC effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298186/global-variables-shared-libraries-and-fpic-effect) as examples (there are several others as well with this problem). However I tried to recompile everything with `-fpic`, also the main module and it still doesn't work. The `-rdynamic` option is unknown so I don't know where this comes from.

I can use classes from the shared library and vice versa, so this affects only global symbols. So what am I doing wrong that the main code and the shared library can not see symbols from each other?

Comment: I guess there is something related to C++'s name mangling mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem why this didn't work for global symbols(no problem with classes).

I'm compiling under cygwin, and apparently the shared object is compiled as a DLL. I tried to look into the library and notized that it is an EXE format and not ELF. So I tried to use the Microsoft DLL syntax for exporting symbols and suddenly it worked. Adding a `__declspec(dllexport)` to the symbol did the trick.

I expected that I would have to use `__declspec(dllimport)` in the main project for importing the symbols, but this doesn't work. Not sure if I missunderstood this parameter or if the cygwin version of gcc does some magic work.

So when you compile a shared library under cygwin it must look like this if you want to export symbols.

Shared library foo.h:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int foo(int a);
```

Shared library foo.cpp:

```
int foo(int a)
{
 ....
}
```

In the executable foo.h:

```
int foo(int a);
```

In the executable main.cpp:

```
main()
{
     foo(1);
}
```

The shared library must be compiled with the `-fpic` switch and linked with `-shared`.

Answer (score 1):

The right approach is to create the instance of the Logger *inside* the shared library, using either a global variable (better if encapsulated in a namespace) or a Singleton class. Then let your main program use it.

Comment: Actually I did use a namespace for some stuff of this. However, I figured, that it would be more logical to let main control the logger, but when I think about your answer, it makes sense, so I guess I will change it accordingly. However, that doesn't answer the underlying question of how to properly share names between the shared library and the main modules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare you variables with default visibility to make it visible to other shared libraries or the main program. It appears that you are compiling with `-fvisibility=hidden`, so that a symbol in the library does not resolve to a definition in the main program or other libraries and vice versa. With the visibility attribute of GCC, you can reverse this effect.

In a nutshell

- **scope** visibility of a declaration across entities of a single object file (global, local, ..)
- **linkage** visibility of a declaration across entities of multiple object files (external, internal)
- **visibility** visibility of a declaration across entities of different shared libraries (default, hidden).

Another possibility is that you are mixing C and C++ code and messing up with the language linkage.

Comment: I didn't know about this visibillty switch, so I'm using the default. thanks for the pointer, I will check out if this is the problem. I guess I have to use namespaces to avoid nameclashes, when I use this switch though, right?